# Proper way to show 3rdpartylicenses.txt in Angular app

Tags: licensing

I am building my Angular app with Angular CLI and it generates `3rdpartylicenses.txt` when I execute a production build.
The file is deployed to the server and therefore is published under `/3rdpartylicenses.txt`.

I would like to know whether I should include an explicit link to `/3rdpartylicenses.txt` into somewhere easily recognizable to the app users.
In [angular.io](https://angular.io/), for example, I cannot find any link to https://angular.io/3rdpartylicenses.txt where they publish OSS licenses just like I do in my app.

Answer (score 4):

If you have an "About" page or some other location where you provide the contact and license information for your app itself I would *highly* suggest putting a link to the `3rdpartylicenses.txt` there. This is a common location for license information and is generally where people will look for it.